# Book I read as a child about a triangular planet where all the natives had triangular eyes.

Tags: story-identification

Book I read as a child about a triangular planet where all the natives had triangular eyes.  A man human, finds a woman semihuman that had wings but were cut by monsters. 
Anyone knows the name of this book?

Comment: Roughly when were you a child? What language was the book in? Do you have any memories of the cover? Can you remember any names of characters? Was the book aimed at any particular age group? Even small details could help us find this.